Multiple displays sometimes forget configuration after suspend
I have multiple displays which I configure via script, something like
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --auto --output DP-0 --auto --left-of HDMI-0

This works, but sometimes -- not always -- after suspend/resume, this configuration is forgotten.
Where can I find logs or other information which will reveal what is happening during suspend/resume which would explain this?

Any further information about the system you are using?

I had the same issue under xfce, and unchecking the "Configure new displays when connected" option did the trick:

(duplicate question: xrandr settings forgotten after suspend/shutdown)
